# Google chrome bug? Select boxes in <th>

Tags: html, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have a table where a select box goes in one on the `<th>` wrappers inside `<thead>`.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem in Google Chrome, where the select box is unresponsive within this tag?

The table has uses: http://autobahn.tablesorter.com/jquery.tablesorter.min.js which perhaps is causing the interference? ( see http://tablesorter.com/docs/ )

```
<th class="{sorter: false}">Location
    <!-- country filter -->
    <select name="countryfilter" id="countryfilter">
        <option value="ANY">SHOW ALL</option>
        <option value="GB">GB</option>
            [etc..]
    </select>
    <!-- end -->
</th>
```

Tried using developer tools, but no JS warnings/errors showed up in Audit.

Comment: can you show your code? I tested and everything works fine.

Comment: hope this is sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select box shows the options in FF Opera IE7/IE8 and Opera. But it fails in chrome, safari and IE9. Safari and Chrome are using webkit so is most certainly a browser implementations issue or an issue with the tablesorter pluigin. Contact the creator of the plugin to have a look at it.

What you can do to work around this, is changing you html to use td in the header,

```
<td class="header">
   <select name="countryfilter" id="countryfilter">
      <option value="ANY">SHOW ALL</option>
      <option value="GB">GB</option>
   </select>
</td>
```

and in the css file for the plugin append `td.header` this will apply the same style for `td` as for the rest of the `th` elements.

```
table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th, 
td.header 
{
   background-color: #e6EEEE;
   border: 1px solid #FFF;
   font-size: 8pt;
   padding: 4px;
}
```